# How to land your first gig as architecture photographer?

Tags: architecture, careers

Let's assume I already understand the basics:

- Exposure (both ambient and using lighting equipments)
- Composition
- Perspective correction
- Large camera movements (tilt/shift/rise ...)
- Image postprocessing, etc etc

And have a portofolio, say consists of relatives/friends houses and public building photos. Then how I should look for my first paid job?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: When there are 20-30 qualified *experienced* photographers for most every commercial job, it's all about who you know that can get you in the door.

Comment: @MichaelC are you suggesting to work as their assistant, say 2 or 3 years, before working on your own?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that unless you know *customers* that need commercial work done you're not likely to get any. If those experienced pros getting work need assistants, they already know dozens of experienced pros to call...

Comment: @MichaelC So you are suggesting to pick different genre for commercial work? I'm thinking about product or wedding... more competitors even on entry level, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm suggesting that all genres of commercial photography (which, by the way - the term "commercial photography" as it is used in the photographic industry doesn't really include wedding photography) currently have far more people already established in the industry trying to get hired than there are jobs available. If you don't have contacts at places that pay folks to do commercial photography, you're going to have a very steep hill to climb. It's far more about who you know and how well you sell yourself than about photographic skill (which you do need - but plenty of others have it, too).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of jobs are referrals. Assuming you had a kit & ability to edit and have a process to deliver a sellable product, ie deliverable page. You got to start somewhere, and it's good to trip over yourself in the process to really learn the ropes. You must learn to sell. If you grab a real yellow pages for your town, you can find unlimited income by cold-calling everyone in that book. Introducing yourself as a new architectural photographer in the area, and you'll be in their area and if you could update their exterior & interior imagery, and wondering if you can set up a time next week Monday or tuesday, would morning or afternoon work better?? Call everyone, because everyone knows someone. If they ask how much, $5 a photo

Comment: Ahh.. "learn to sell". Something we, enthusiasts usually forget that professional photography isn't about your technical skill alone...